# gwt-unitCacheXXXX files in the gwt project

Tags: git, gwt

We are trying to source control our gwt +gae for java project and i am seeing files starting with gwt-unitCache appearing in the changes from the root folder of the app. should we source control these?

Comment: No these should be in your ignore pattern.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663465/setup-a-gwt-project-correctly-with-svn-and-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setup a GWT Project correctly with SVN and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663465/setup-a-gwt-project-correctly-with-svn-and-eclipse) answer the question very well. I think people should search before posting questions