# NetworkError: 404 Not Found on firefox

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

We have a gwt app deployed on gae for java. The app runs fine in google chrome but fails with below exception on ie and firefox

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.sakshum.org/adminmodule/67883654A8944A4C561CF25763FB1D79.cache.html

based on  [Setup a GWT Project correctly with SVN and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663465/setup-a-gwt-project-correctly-with-svn-and-eclipse) we have excluded the files in adminmodule directory to upload to app engine.

Please advise what is reason for it to fail and how to make it working.

The ignored patterns are:

```
.svn
*.bak
classes/
thumbs.db
*.class
.gwt*
gwt-unitCache/
deploy/
war/adminmodule/
war/sakshumwebgae/
sakshumweb/war/WEB-INF/deploy/adminmodule/
sakshumweb/war/sakshumwebgae/
.bin
*.orig
```

Comment: A site that can be found only in Google Chrome? strange.

Comment: well it basically makes to fail loading of gwt modules. and hence what may happen is the site renders but the form built using gwt does not

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the gwt application for all browsers? Also are you getting this error in hosted mode too?

Comment: what do you mean by compiling for all the browsers? I never know how to do that? i just compile and run the app usually in chrome and then deploy to app engine. no i dont get that in hosted mode

Comment: @SSR when you forget to specifically build for one client, doesn't it usually alert the user of that client that the site isn't built for it?

Comment: @dlamblin i dont think so and in fact i still dont know how to compile for all the broswers

Comment: @Vik your module's get.xml file can specify which user-agents to build for. If it inherits com.google.gwt.user.User as is usual it should be buildling for all the supported ones. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml

Comment: Compile the application with PRETTY mode and use firebug to view the error in console. Attach the same in the question. Also check whether you have the 67883654A8944A4C561CF25763FB1D79.cache.html in your adminmodule folder ( the filename changes for every gwt compilation and for every browser language permutation )

Comment: @SSR well I am not uploading any of the file from war/adminmodule/ folder so obviously it wont be there in the app engine. I was told that anything in this folder should not be uploaded and is generated by app engine itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get 404. **HORROR!!!!**

Currently only /deploy/ folder can be ignored and not war/gwtmodule.

All the gwt generated scripts are in war/gwtmodule and you need to upload them per compilation into appengine.

These are generated every build in compilation phase and hence are not checked into svn.

**They need to be in deployment folder for APP Engine.**

I suggest you go through the GWT teams excellent document for App Engine with GWT https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine

Edit -
`<modulename>.nocache.js` loads `<longnumeric>.cache.html` based on browser * language permutation. GWT compiles your java code to create the `<modulename>.nocache.js` and the relevant cache.html files. cache and nocache indicates whether browser is supposed to cache or not cache the file.

You will have the .nocache.js script reference in your html file for the gwtapp.

Comment: so i uploaded these folders but i still see 404. how do i generated the missing file "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.sakshum.org/adminmodule/B1EB2F7690910F9D605FC16A008BE9F0.cache.html" on server ?

Comment: There cannot be a missing file! GWT cach.html reference might not have refreshed. Ctrl+Shift+Del to ensure your browser is not playing tricks.

Comment: I would guess you need to set up a sample hello world in gwt with gae to understand the basic concepts instead of randomly trying out stackoverflow q/a.. session. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the GWT compiler to build different javascript files for each permutation. A permutation is for a specific user-agent (browser, eg ie9 gecko (ff), webkit (chrome/safari)) and language (English, French). So you've correctly uploaded all the output files for the chrome browser, presumably in English. It would seem, as you say, that you're filtering out other files from uploading, and that some of those files are requested when using a different permutation for Firefox in English. You should try not to filter those files.

Comment: my application does not have translation stuff. its just english. So, do you mean i need to remove some entries from the ignore list as i posted in my question? if yes then which one?

Comment: @Vik, I think it might be this line, sakshumweb/war/WEB-INF/deploy/adminmodule/ I'm not familiar with using GWT on GAE though, so I don't know why it'd be advised to filter it.

Comment: Its not expert skill. The war/gwtmodule needs to be uploaded to appengine.